# Computing the stationary distribution of a markov chain

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

I have a markov chain with transition matrix below,

$$\begin{bmatrix} 
 1-q     & q     &   &      &   \\
 1-q     & 0     & q  &      &   \\
      & 1-q     & 0  & q     &   \\
      &      & 1-q  &  0    & q  \\
      &      &   & \ddots     & \ddots & \ddots
\end{bmatrix}$$
and I am asked to compute the stationary distribution for $q<\frac{1}{2}$. Using $\pi P =\pi$, I get that $\pi_n =\pi_0\left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^n$ and $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \pi_n = 1$.

Thus I get

$\pi_0\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^n=1 \\ \pi_0=\frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^n} \\ \text{thus } \pi_n = \frac{\left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^n}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^n}$

But it doesnt seem to be simplified. Is there anything else I can do to simplify $\pi_0=\frac{1}{\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^n}$? And thus simplify $\pi_n$.

Comment: Since $q < \frac{1}{2}$, $\gamma = \frac{q}{1-q} < 1$, so the sum in the denominator is a geometric series.

Comment: Thanks @Neal, so I get that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\frac{q}{1-q}\right)^n =\frac{q}{1-2q}$, hence $\pi_0 = \frac{1-2q}{2q}$?

Comment: I get $\sum\gamma^n = \frac{1}{1-\gamma} = \frac{1}{1-\frac{q}{1-q}} = \frac{1-q}{1-2q}$ so $\pi_0 = \frac{1-2q}{1-q}$.